# 'Started bpfilter' after log in

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Ubuntu mate 18.04. For now, it has always worked perfectly... Until this afternoon, when I turned it on as usual and it appeared a screen that requires me my sudo password (I never had to do this before), after log in it appears 'started bpfilter' and then, I have to type my password all over again. I'm stuck there and I can't go ahead.

None of the solutions given on the Internet fix my problem (GRUB, Nvidia controllers...). I'm gonna try to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

For me there were 3 steps to follow to fix this:

1. log into TTY terminal so you can access command line. Some users say you can just type user_name -> return -> password -> return. (Didn't work for me) I needed to do CNTRL-ALT-F2 and login with username & password
2. Update and upgrade packages with: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

That may have fixed it, if there are no warnings on missing gpu packages just do `sudo reboot`

3. I had a warning after the update on Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_scm.bin for module amdgpu

If you have that or a similar warning which hints that it could be fixed by: update-initramfs, then you need git installed (I won't go into that here) once you have git do: `cd ~Documents && git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`   then to copy the files and update initramfs do: `sudo cp ~/Documents/linux-firmware/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu && sudo update-initramfs -k all -u -v`

Then do `sudo reboot`

Answer (score -2):

I also faced this problem and I solved by just entering: "ctrl + alt + F1".

I found this solution from google. Actually this is the key to switch between UI and Terminal.